# Showing that localization is an exact functor

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, localization

I'm again in this awfully familiar situation where I'm struggling to prove simple statements mostly because I have no idea how a template of a proof should look like in this specified context.

I'm trying to prove these two statements:

1. Given a multiplicative subset of a ring $S \subset R$.  The localization functor from $R-Mod$ to $S^{-1}R-Mod$ defined by: $$M \mapsto S^{-1}M ,\phi \mapsto S^{-1}\phi=(\frac{m}{s} \mapsto \frac{\phi(m)}{s}) $$ Preserves homology of all complexes.
2. Let $A \to B \to C$ be a complex in $R-Mod$. If all localization by prime ideals $\mathfrak p \subset R$ make $A_{\mathfrak p} \to B_{\mathfrak p} \to C_{\mathfrak p}$ exact in $R_{\mathfrak p} -Mod$ then $A \to B \to C$ is itself exact.

   ---

My actual problem with both questions is that i keep getting confused by torsion elements of the modules and if annhilators intersect the multiplicative set i'm stuck altogether...

I think it's a partly language barrier so I would be really thankful if whoever answers this question will give a detailed answer that would demonstrate a correct and elegant use of the relevant language and tools in this context.

Comment: For the second part, see [this question of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121159/12885) for different proofs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is enough to prove it preserves short exact sequences: $\;0\to M\to N\to P\to 0$. As the tensor product is right-exact, and $S^{-1}M\simeq M\otimes_A S^{-1}A$, it is even enough to prove it preserves injectivity.

So consider an injective morphism $\varphi\colon M\to N$ and suppose $\;(S^{-1}\varphi)\Bigl(\dfrac ms\Bigr)=0$ in $S^{-1}N$. This means there exists $t\in S$ such that $\;t\mkern1mu\varphi(m)=\varphi(tm)=0$. But then
$$\frac ms=\frac{tm}{ts}=\frac0{ts}=0,$$
which shows $\;S^{-1}\varphi\;$  is injective.

Comment: Thanks, I went to read about tensor products and it clicked. One more example of where something elementary becomes trivial with more machinery.

Comment: Could you teach me why  tm/ts＝0/ts ?

Comment: @bellow: Very gladly. That is because $\varphi(tm)=0$ and $\varphi$ is injective by hypothesis,  so $tm=0$.

Comment: Great, I understood.Thank you.

Comment: Sorry to bother you,but why there exists t∈S s.t tφ（m）＝0? not tφ（m/s）？

Comment: You don't bother me. That is due to how we can see that $m/s=0$ in a module of fractions:  the condition is that there is a $t\in S$ such that $tm=0$. Happy New Year, by the way!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I'm very happy. Happy new year !!

Comment: From S^-1φ（m/s）＝0, how we got ヨt∈S,tφ（m）＝０？

Comment: I feel like my notation was ambiguous: $S^{-1}\varphi$ is the extension of $\varphi$ to a $S^{-1}R$-homomorphism from $S^{-1}M$ to $S^{-1}N$. Explicitly, the image of $\dfrac ms$ is $\dfrac{\varphi(m)}s$. Does it answer to your question?