# How to determine the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ of the variety $X=V(xy)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$ at $p=(0,0)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, affine-varieties

As in the title I am trying to solve the following execrcise:

> Compute the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ of the variety $X=V(xy)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$ at $p=(0,0)$.
>   Show it is isomorphic to $A=\{(f_1,f_2)|f_1(0)=f_2(0)\}\subset\mathcal{O}_1\oplus\mathcal{O}_2$ where $\mathcal{O}_i$ are two copies of the local ring of $\mathbb{A}^1$ at $p=0$, i.e. $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1,0}$

My attempt is to exploit the isomorphism, which holds for any affine variety$$K[X]_{\mathcal{m}_p}\cong \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$$ where $K[X]_{\mathcal{m}_p}$ is the localization of the algebra of regular functions on $X$, at the maximal ideal of the point $p$.

Then since $I(X)=(xy)$ and $\mathcal{m}_p=(x,y)$ I get: 
$$\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\cong (\frac{K[x,y]}{(xy)})_{(x,y)}$$

Here I am getting a bit confused with quotients and localization so:

**Doubt 1**: Letting $z_1=x+(xy),z_2=y+(xy)$, is it true that $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\cong (K[z_1,z_2])_{(z_1,z_2)}$ ? Something here does not convince me.

Then I have $\mathcal{O}_i=\{\frac{f}{g}|f,g\in K[t], g(0)\neq 0\}$, but I am a bit clueless on how to find the desired isomoprhism. So:

**Doubt 2**: How to prove $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\cong A$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For (1), do you know that localization is exact and therefore commutes with quotients? For (2), if you're having issues with the local ring case, you can try to prove the global isomorphism and then localize (that is, show that $k[x,y]/(xy)\cong \{(f,g)\subset k[x]\times k[y] \mid f(0)=g(0)\}$ and then localize).

Comment: @KReiser  No, actaully I was not told much about localization  other than the definiton and its direct consequences. You mean exactness in the functorial sense (as Hom, and tensor product)? Actally I did not reflect at all about the functorial nature of localization, which should justify also your second hint? Am I wrong? Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me expand my comments in to an answer.

First, [localization is exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398185/showing-that-localization-is-an-exact-functor), and therefore commutes with quotients: if $0\to A\to B\to B/A\to 0$ is exact, then $0\to S^{-1}A\to S^{-1}B \to S^{-1}(B/A)\to 0$ is exact, and the final term is also isomorphic to $(S^{-1}B)/(S^{-1}A)$. In your case, this implies that $\left(K[x,y]/(xy)\right)_{(\overline{x},\overline{y})}\cong k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(xy)_{(x,y)}$ where the overline denotes taking the image inside $k[x,y]/(xy)$. This should resolve your first question.

For your second question, one way to do it is to first understand the global picture: one can write $k[x,y]/(xy)$ as the subring of $k[x]\times k[y]$ of polynomials having equal constant term. Localization at the maximal ideal corresponding to the origin means inverting all polynomials on both sides which do not vanish at the origin: in particular, any polynomial in $k[x]\times k[y]$ of the form $(c+xp(x),c)$ or $(c,c+yq(y))$ is inverted, so we can write this localization as the subring of $k[x]_{(x)}\times k[y]_{(y)}$ consisting of polynomials with equal constant terms. As $k[x]_{(x)}$ is the local ring of $\Bbb A^1_k$ at the origin, we are done.